# how PCRF and PCEF share the static rules information

Tags: 3g, lte, umts

when PCRF needs to provision a static rule for a session, how PCRF determines a static rule which is predefined in PCEF ? Do they share common database ?

Answer (score 1):

"To activate/deactivate a rule, PCRF has to give the rule name to PCEF, how PCRF knows the rule name in the first place, that is my question"

so the pre-define name should exist in overall solution document, based on solution, these names was known by PCRF~~

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning or removal of PCC rules from PCRF to PCEF is over Gx reference point. The static or predefined PCC rules shall be preconfigured in the PCEF which can be activated or deactivated by the PCRF at any time.

The PCRF PCC rule decisions may be based on information obtained from Application Function (AF) via Rx interface, information obtained from SPR via the Sp interface, information obtained from BBERF via the Gxx interface,
information obtained from PCEF via Gx interface and own PCRF pre-configured information.

Comment: I already read this from the spec, but i am confused about "predefined PCC rules shall be preconfigured in the PCEF which can be activated or deactivated by the PCRF at any time". To activate/deactivate a rule, PCRF has to give the rule name to PCEF, how PCRF knows the rule name in the first place, that is my question.

Comment: Administrator types it in